# How to set color of child QLabels while hover parent QFrame with QSS?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to set the hover state color of 2 labels inside a QFrame with a stylesheet, but the frame takes the hover states regardless if there is an actual hover:

See screenshot:
[image]

I've got a QFrame with QLabels. I set the default colors to green and purple. While i hover the QFrame, the color of both labels should go red.

The [exact same CSS does work with html](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/olwHs), but i can't seem to get it to work with the QT stylesheets.

```
div{background-color:black; width:200px; height:100px;}

#label1{color: green;}
#label2{color: purple;}

div:hover #label1 {color: red;}
div:hover #label2 {color:red;}
```

Comment: QLabels are QFrames. Maybe that's why your CSS isn't working properly? Also, you're missing semicolons. I've seen that cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not do it with `QLabel`. It's limitation of QSS. Try to use `QToolButton` instead of `QLabel` (and customize `QToolButton` to look like `QLabel`).

Possible you shuld use `QToolButton` instead of `QFrame` too.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with Qt5.9 and your code still does not work. I have the same behaviour as you.

But, with this simple QSS code I get the label's text to be blue, and red when hovered.

```
QLabel {color:blue}
QFrame:hover {color:red}
```

---

This does not work when using the object-name, probably because of the [conflict resolution](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution) of QSS.

```
#label {color:blue}
QFrame:hover {color:red}
```